# Are these questions about women's clothing all the same?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm looking at these questions:

- [What does Islam say about women's clothing?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/88/11593) asked Jun 2012
- [What should the Hijab for Muslim women cover?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/763/11593) asked Jun 2012
- [Why scholars disagree on whether it's obligatory for women to veil their faces or not in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2474/11593) asked Sep 2012
- [Are women required to cover their face and palms in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5607/11593) asked Nov 2012
- [Is it permissible for to have hajib which makes her look attractive to the opposite sex and that is fashionable?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8562/11593) asked Jun 2013
- [Veiling of men and women in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23703/11593) asked Mar 2015

They all look to me like they're covering the same ground (except maybe the third one and the last one). I'm wondering:

- Should they all (but one, of course) be closed as duplicates?
- Are there other questions that should be closed as dupes of one of these as well?
- Should they be scoped better for a specific madhab's interpretation? Or is their current scope (asking what "Islam" says) fine?

<sub>**Note**: If any are closed, keep in mind that [you don't have to choose which to close based on the age of the question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/266429)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Here's my observation on each question:

> What does Islam say about women's clothing? asked Jun 2012

This question is about clothing in general.

> What should the Hijab for Muslim women cover? asked Jun 2012

This question is about 'extent' of covering.

> Why scholars disagree on whether it's obligatory for women to veil
>   their faces or not in Islam? asked Sep 2012

This question is about finding the 'reasons' behind the disagreements.

> Are women required to cover their face and palms in Islam? asked Nov
>   2012

This question is specific to upper bounds of Hijab; i.e. specialized sub-topic.

> Is it permissible for to have hajib which makes her look attractive to
>   the opposite sex and that is fashionable? asked Jun 2013

This question is about going the very opposite to the purpose of Hijab.

> Veiling of men and women in Islam asked Mar 2015

This question brings the factor of 'men's hijab' into the scenario.

Answer (score -1):

You see, the very reason why there are those many permutations of those questions is because there is wide disagreement among scholars thereby nations and so people are curios about each and every aspect, whether to leave the face uncovered or not is the biggest issue, and hence it is a truth question.

So, as you've suggested [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1571/11938), those permutations are covering minor aspects separately (yeah some are duplicates & are most likely to get closed I think but need to create perfect mappings though). Maybe, we could scope those madhabs based. But again, this issue, people don't like to call it as madhab based and only mere Islamic based because there are rulings directly from Qur'an but what lies is the difference in the exegesis and belief in certain Hadith as covered in [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/23858/11938).