# Request to reopen a closed question #14985

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, re-open

Here's the [link](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/15709) to the review made of a question with nearly 500 views, actually if counted, there were altogether 4 votes on 'let it be open' vs 1 vote on 'let it be closed'.

4 votes

- Me
- Sayyid
- One who asked the question
- Another guy in the comments of that question(not visible now)

vs

1 vote

- Mr Gold.

What I mean to infer is maybe, this is truth based or just opinion based(maybe I donno), but this is a contemporary issue and we think this needs some light to be shred on *in this site too*. Or maybe we could 'edit' it to suit the site rules.

**Support:**

https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/113/11938

(I don't know if I can point out those users here by name who reviewed the question, if I shouldn't have done, I'm sorry)

Requesting you to oblige,

Yours faithfully...

:)

Comment: The exact reason I gave for closing it in the first place: "This is a matter in which there is an obvious difference of opinion, and as phrased is highly likely to attract Truth claims instead of actual answers.  See relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1442/22" I had already deleted one answer that was nothing but polemic before closing the question, and saw no reason to expect that situation would improve without significant editing.

Comment: how do you decide if something is a truth claim, there must be a poll for it like anything else. Also I think there are a few more questions left out there which I feel are truth claims too. So thereby I've included this as an off-topic reason. Either it passes as an off-topic reason, or this question has to be reopened under the community poll,i.e. if community decides to let it be open. @goldPseudo

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser I am gathering evidence and instances of when pseudoGold has abused his powers, thinking he knows whats best for the community. His interpretation of what Truth is not defined properly nor the users of the site know what exactly it is. In a site that's uses **community votes, he regularly bypasses the votes** and does as he wishes. This is not how the SE network works. I will send the gathered evidence to SE and just let them deal with hit.

Comment: @masfenix This does not appear to be an instance of abuse. SE sites are not popular-vote democracies. Mods are _supposed_ to make such judgment calls and intervene when posts are outside site guidelines. How popular they are or how many users express dissenting opinions is irrelevant—the question you need to be asking is whether the question that got closed actually fits the site guidelines or not. If you can make a case that it does then use that as your argument on meta for why a different judgment call should be made.

Comment: @Caleb This particular instance may not be. I commented to get in contact with OP. I am not sure if his judgement is correct. He's deleted a few of my comments which I believe were perfectly fine, but apparently didn't meet his definition of constructive. It's ironic because he's made a few comments himself that are borderline rude. In any case, I am not explaining myself anymore. I am just collecting evidence which will later be sent to the SE team and let them decide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For it to be a good fit for SE, I think **one of three** things needs to happen:

1. It should ask for a yes or no from the perspective of a particular madhhab.
2. It should ask what arguments exist in favor of the practice.
3. It should ask what arguments exist against the practice.

As it is, it just asks, "Which position is true?" and leaves it open for people to give their opinions and polemics and for voters to choose which ones they "agree" with. Not a good fit for SE.

Comment: This seems to have a pretty much informative answer. :)

Comment: maybe you could try to answer [this](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/is-there-any-way-to-make-truth-questions-constructive)

Answer (score 6):

I agree it should be closed. How does that question have anything to do with the topic of Islam? The academic/critical study of Islam?

It's a question that will attract answers to one's interpretation of Islam. Some may believe its okay according to their teachers, another may think its not okay. How do you tell who is right? We are not a place for debates, its not like the person who has the most convincing argument and the most hadiths cited "wins" the argument. The question has no binary answer.

It is precisely a truth question, off limits for this site.